# expresion regular que acepte numeros del 0-9 y el signo $

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer que un campo de tipo texto solo acepte este formato

```
<input type="text" class="form-control s18 no-pad displayInlineBlock" id="tarifa" name="tarifa" maxlength="30" required pattern="[^a-zA-Z0-9]">
```

ejemplo : **$ 12,000.00**
hasta el momento solo me acepta del 0-9

Comment: ¿Puedes agregas que has intentado?  o que expresión tienes que no te funciona? Recuerda [**_¿Como Preguntar?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Vos lo que buscas es que la persona tipee los puntos de miles? o solo la coma?

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que te deje, si logre resolver tu problema dale un +1 a la respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: No eso ya lo hace el javascrip con el siguiguente codigo // var amount = $(e.target).val().replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2})$/, '$1.$2')
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, ",");
 $(e.target).val("$ " + amount);

Comment: Entonces no entiendo ¿que necesitas hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza esta expresion regular `^[0-9,$]*$` para permitir que solo en el input se puedan enviar valores numericos junto a un signo peso o dolar.

```
<input type="text" name="text" pattern="^[0-9,$]*$">
```

Si deseas agregar un mensaje personalizado para el error que produce html5 utiliza un 'title' dentro del input con tu mensaje